# Windows 10 automatically switches between active windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, browser

I usually have two browser windows open when I'm working on my PC (one for working and one for watching online TV - not on an app).

Problem is, that while I am typing away in the active browser window, it will suddenly **automatically switch to the other browser window** which results in a bunch of "return to previous page" via backspace, muting the 'TV', scrolling around and other crazy annoying things (during the time it took me to type this so far I have exited the TV show I'm watching 4 times...).

**This is not a keyboard-shortcut issue** since it also happens when I'm just reading something without touching any keys. I simply want the window I selected and am working in to STAY as the active window and **not automatically switch to the other window without warning**.

Does anyone know how to fix this or turn it off?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this Windows Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3we7z6/firefox_windows_come_into_focus_automatically/), it appears someone else found a resolution for this issue. Below is a quote from the article:

> After an hour, and four background changes, behavior has stopped using
>   this tip: changing Firefox's browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground
>   setting in about:config to true.

Comment: I confirm. FF is trying to work in the background and some pages may cause it to try to become the active window. It has been reported to them, the config is a good temporary solution until it gets patched.

Comment: On going to `about:config` and setting `browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground` to `true`. - It might have helped to some extent, not sure.. I _**am sure**_ I have seen this problem _even_ when I have set it to true.